# To schedule a hive query on Crontab

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Can any one help me to schedule a job in Crontab which will execute a simple Hive query on specific time and provide me the output in text/log file.

I have created a batch script to execute a select query , but getting error("Hive command not found") while executing it in Crontab. However same script is running fine through shell. Below is my script :

```
ip.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting of Job"
cd /home/hadoop/work/hive/bin
hive -e 'select * from mytest.empl'
echo "Script ends here"
```

Crontab:
10 * * * * /home/hadoop/work/ip.sh >> /home/hadoop/work/quryout.log 2>&1

After executing the Crontab , I am getting below message in log:

Output(Queryout.log):
Starting Of Job
hive command not found in ip.sh at line number 4
Script ends here

Comment: Please format your question better, use text in between the ` character to inline code

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines in your `/home/hadoop/.bashrc`:

```
export HIVE_HOME=/home/hadoop/work/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
```

Now, change your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting of Job"
hive -e 'select * from mytest.empl'
echo "Script ends here"
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. After adding the env variable, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this in shell script

```
/home/hadoop/work/hive/bin/hive -e 'select * from mytest.empl'
```