# Is it possible to schedule CRON task for a python file using hive

Tags: python, python-3.x, hive, cron-task

I want to schedule a CRON job of a python file (ex: test.py) present at a server location (ex: X.X.X.X/home/myname/test.py). The CRON has to be set up using hive.

I did some research and found the below articles that came close to what I want to do.
[To schedule a hive query on Crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521650/to-schedule-a-hive-query-on-crontab)

```
echo "Starting of Job"
hive -e 'select * from mytest.empl'
echo "Script ends here"
```

I want the hive query to be replaced by code which enable it to run the python file.

Comment: I found what I was exactly looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377109/shell-script-execute-a-python-program-from-within-a-shell-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive is a framework for data warehousing on top of Hadoop and has nothing to do with cron scheduling. A cron schedule is a simple text file located under `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` on Linux systems. You can access it using the `crontab` command. For example, to open crontab file, you need to issue this command:

```
crontab -e
```

Each line in crontab is an entry with an expression and a command to run:

You can add something like this to the crontab:

```
* * * * * /path/to/your/python-job.py >> ~/python-job.log 2>&1
```

This entry is added to run the mentioned python script (python-job.py) every single second.

You can follow this [link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) to see how to add jobs to cron under Linux or UNIX. Check out this [link](https://crontab.guru/) to quickly generate the cron schedule expressions.

Comment: Thank you for the information.
I was looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377109/shell-script-execute-a-python-program-from-within-a-shell-script